# Fastest database design for keyword queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am working on a Ruby on Rails site that is going to have a set of records that can be tagged with one or more keywords. Quite similar to the way questions on this site can be tagged with keywords.

The Rails way to do this would be to have a many-to-many relationship between the records and the keywords. But I'm wondering if this join is going to slow down searches when there are lots of records.

In particular, I'm going to need to do searches on multiple keywords, such as 'give me all the records that are tagged with keyword A, F, and G'. I'm not sure how well Rails would optimize this type of query.

Any ideas on the best way to structure the models and/or controller for this type of app?

Comment: Similar question as [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234796/optimal-data-architecture-for-tagging-clouds-and-searching-like-stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234796/optimal-data-architecture-for-tagging-clouds-and-searching-like-stackoverflow)?

Comment: Bill: thanks for the reference. Very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a typical foriegn key relationship between records and keywords (tags) can work pretty well as a storage structure; if you are so concerned about faster access to the same why not add a caching layer like `memcached` to your application: Adds to the program complexity but is known to give significant performance benefits for `read` operations.

Comment: Ah... I think you've hit it for my particular app. Fetching all the records for one tag is obviously very efficient, its when you are finding the intercept of 3 tags, say, that things get slow. But Rails has SQL caching built in, so the first hit on a set would be slow, but subsequent hits fast. Problem solved. Thanks.